# Get Id Based on Dynamic Selected Values in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have several `productOptionTypes` with dynamic values. My problem is how do I match it with its `variants`. I want to get the `variant id` based on it.

Pls check codesandbox here [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-v3-with-hooks-and-form-forked-6zl4v?file=/src/index.js:442-946)

```
{productOptionTypes.map((item, index) => (
  <>
    <span className="title">{item.optionName}</span>
    <Select
      placeholder={`${item?.optionValues?.length} ${item.optionName}s`}
      options={item.optionValues.map((option) => {
        return { label: option, value: option };
      })}
      isSearchable={false}
      onChange={(value) => handleSelectVariant(value, index)}
    />
  </>
))}
```

Comment: Are you trying to use the product option type values to search/filter the variants data? What do you want to store in the `variantType` state? How do you want the data to relate?

Comment: @DrewReese. I just want to store the data from the `handleSelectVariant` cause my goal is just to filter just to get the `variant id` based on it.

Comment: I'm tinkering in your sandbox, but what isn't clear is the UX. It sounds like you want a single variant's `id`, but it isn't clear how these two collections relate, other than via the option types. What are you trying to match by? You want an absolute single result, or are you looking for an array of variant `id` that match? Are you using a single option type/value, or multiple?

Comment: @DrewReese. I want to output console.log a `single variant id`.  It related in a sense that when you select from the dropdown you compare it to the variants array

Comment: You should explain how you want the select options and variants array to be compared.

Comment: @DrewReese. It matches based on the optionName and optionValues selected. As you can see in the `variants` array, it has option1Type, option2Type.... and also option1value, option2Value and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best I could come up with is this:

1. Update the option mapping to return the option name, to be used as the foreign key into the `variants` array objects, i.e. "Color", "Size", etc.

   ```
   options={item.optionValues.map((option) => {
     return {
       label: option,
       value: option,
       name: item.optionName
     };
   })}
   ```
2. Update the `variantType` state to be an object, and update the `handleSelectVariant` handler to store the variant types by the foreign key "name" and the selected "value"

   ```
   const [variantType, setSelectedVariant] = useState({});

   const handleSelectVariant = (value, index) => {
     setSelectedVariant((state) => ({
       ...state,
       [value.name]: value.value
     }));
   };
   ```
3. Use a `filter` and `every` function to reduce the option types and values to a filtered result of variants that can be easily mapped to the `id` properties.

   ```
   const matches = variants
     .filter((variant) => {
       return [
         ["option1Value", "option1Type"],
         ["option2Value", "option2Type"],
         ["option3Value", "option3Type"],
         ["option4Value", "option4Type"],
         ["option5Value", "option5Type"],
         ["option6Value", "option6Type"],
         ["option7Value", "option7Type"],
         ["option8Value", "option8Type"],
         ["option9Value", "option9Type"],
         ["option10Value", "option10Type"]
       ].every(([key, valueKey]) =>
         variantType[variant[valueKey]]
           ? variant[key] === variantType[variant[valueKey]]
           : true
       );
     })
     .map(({ id }) => id);
   ```

## Demo

[image: Edit get-id-based-on-dynamic-selected-values-in-react]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. By the way, optionValue and optionType are dynamic. meaning if there is up to 10, then it has `option10Value` and `option10Type`

Comment: I see you just added static. By the way, sometimes in here says 'Cannot ready property 'Color' of null. In here `variantChosen[variant[valueKey]]`

Comment: @Joseph Interesting, what options had you selected to cause that error?

Comment: I think the first one. but sometimes it happens, sometimes not. Maybe you can add a safe operator...?

Comment: @Joseph Is the error in ***my*** codesandbox? After selecting colors for a minute straight I don't see any error. What are the steps (reproduction steps) you are doing to induce error?

Comment: Its on my actual API. maybe on asynchronous problems. Maybe you can add safe conditions/operators?

Comment: @Joseph Maybe I'm misunderstanding something but why is your UI usable if you haven't fetch all the data yet? You could apply some conditional rendering so the select inputs aren't rendered until the options are available.

Comment: Alright. By the way could you make your optionValue and optionType dynamic? What if there are hundreds of it?

Comment: @Joseph I'm assuming you are referring to the `optionXType` and `optionXValue` key-value pairs in variants.js? IMO the easiest way would be to use a structure that more easily lends itself to storing dynamic values, i.e. an array of options, then the separate map wouldn't be necessary. The alternative would be to process the variants array objects and "pick out" these key-value pairs.

Comment: Could you add that answer here? Thank you.

Comment: @Joseph Here https://codesandbox.io/s/get-id-based-on-dynamic-selected-values-in-react-forked-2z385

Comment: Thank you. maybe you can add some conditions so asynchronous error won't appear like `filter of undefined` etc....

Comment: @Joseph Adding a null-check for possibly undefined values is a trivial matter, and to be honest, out of scope for this question since asynchronous logic isn't part of filtering data based on user selections (what you asked about). You should ensure you have valid initial state, use conditional rendering until your selection data is ready, or use null-checks to not filter on undefined objects.

Comment: No problem. You've done enough. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

When i understand it correctly you want to safe every selected value, then compare the result to your variants and select the variantId of the item matching all selctboxes based on it?

index.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Select from "react-select";
import "./styles.css";
import { productOptionTypes } from "./productOptionTypes";
import { variants } from "./variants";

function App() {
  const [variantType, setSelectedVariant] = useState({});
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);

  const mapIndexKey = {
    0: "option1Value",
    1: "option2Value",
    2: "option3Value",
    3: "option4Value"
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setResult(
      variants.filter(
        (el) =>
          el.option1Value == variantType.option1Value &&
          el.option2Value == variantType.option2Value &&
          el.option3Value == variantType.option3Value &&
          el.option4Value == variantType.option4Value
      )
    );
  }, [variantType]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(result);
  }, [result]);

  const handleSelectVariant = (value, index) => {
    setSelectedVariant({ ...variantType, [mapIndexKey[index]]: value.value });
    console.log(variantType, value, index);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        {productOptionTypes.map((item, index) => (
          <>
            <span className="title">{item.optionName}</span>
            <Select
              placeholder={`${item?.optionValues?.length} ${item.optionName}s`}
              options={item.optionValues.map((option) => {
                return { label: option, value: option };
              })}
              isSearchable={false}
              onChange={(value) => handleSelectVariant(value, index)}
            />
          </>
        ))}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

variants.js

```
export const variants = [
  {
    id: "60451fd290aeb720d96d8459",
    name: "Women's Bellarina Half Toe Grip Yoga Pilates Barre Socks",
    wholesalePrice: "8.0",
    sku: "s01524blk",
    option1Type: "Color",
    option1Value: "Black",
    option2Type: "Size",
    option2Value: "XS",
    option3Type: "Toe Type",
    option3Value: "Half Toe",
    option4Value: "Bellarina",
    retailPrice: "16.0",
    __typename: "Variant"
  },
  {
    id: "60451fd790aeb720d96d8463",
    name: "Women's Bellarina Half Toe Grip Yoga Pilates Barre Socks",
    wholesalePrice: "8.0",
    sku: "s01525blk",
    option1Type: "Color",
    option1Value: "Black",
    option2Type: "Size",
    option2Value: "S",
    option3Type: "Toe Type",
    option3Value: "Half Toe",
    retailPrice: "16.0",
    __typename: "Variant"
  }
}
```

Basicly what i do is saving all selected values in a map and everytime a value is changed just comparing it to all variants, if a variant is equal i select it.
For one variant i added the fourth key "Bellarina".

I hope this solution solves your problem.

When you want to verify the solution just select the first value of every selectbox and have a look at the console.

Comment: can you fork my codesandbox so I can check easily. Thanks. By the way, options are dynamic

Comment: Do i need a codesandbox account? I pressed fork but i dont have an account.... can you see the fork nevertheless?

Comment: Yeah, it will create a new link when you fork. You can paste the new link here